# Max message size over the wire?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ashx

I have a file input field that base64 encodes a selected image to be sent to my handler (IHttpHandler).

*What is the maximum or how do I found out what the maximum request size I can send to my handler?*

The file will not be larger than 500kB, but I dont' know if that is too big or not, and given the nature of base64 encoding, it inflates the filesize ~33%.

UPDATE: Thank you all for the helpful answers and comments!

Comment: The max size is 4096kb(4mb).  There is a config setting called maxRequestLength which can be used to adjust this.

Comment: @AliK Thanks. Could you check out the comment I posted on the answer below?

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327452/which-gets-priority-maxrequestlength-or-maxallowedcontentlength)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max request size is driven by a setting in web.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="nnnn" />
```

The default is 4MB.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: May I ask why [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920985/generic-handler-parameter-size-limit?rq=1) says 30 million bytes is set by default, or that just for a different parameter? What is the difference between the 2 parameters? `maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength`

Comment: @Josh maxRequestLength is ASP.NET specific, whereas maxAllowedContentLength is for all requests served by IIS, ASP.NET or not.

Comment: maxRequestLength is to set a limit to the full request message size in your .NET app. maxAllowedContentLength is for the content part of a request message in IIS.