# send message from javascript to handler

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, httphandler

I have client code running in javascript which tries
to send html content to a custom handler.

The client side code looks like this:

```
   ...
    $('#txt_content').val($(div).html());
        performClick($('#submit_excel_form'));
```

And the handler code is:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string name = context.Request["txt_name"];
            string content = context.Request["txt_content"];
           ...
        }
```

The problem is that when using Chrome browser, the message the handler get
(txt_content) is not complete.
Maximum length of string I get is: 524288

When I run in explorer , I get the full message (with length=567130).

I saw a similar quesion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920985/generic-handler-parameter-size-limit), but it was not answered
(The solution with setting maxAllowedContentLength doesn't work).

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks,
Omer

**Edit:**

This is the relevant part from the configuration file:

```
<webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="Default.aspx">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="Default.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
    <globalization culture="he-IL" uiCulture="he-IL" resourceProviderFactoryType="BusinessLogic.Culture.CultureProviderFactory" enableClientBasedCulture="false"/>
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Messaging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="2097151" requestLengthDiskThreshold="8192000"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
    <pages clientIDMode="Static" validateRequest="false">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="amr" namespace="BusinessLogic.Controls" assembly="BusinessLogic"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Infrastructure"/>
        <add namespace="CommonData"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
        <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the reason for it either. Perhaps add further information about your configuration, and show the form you're submitting.

Comment: Thanks , I've added the config sections, the html is created dynamically, I'm not sure if it will be useful to add it here.

Comment: What version of .net are you on?

Answer (score 1):

You can likely get around this limit/bug with a multipart post.

A full, but complicated, example of doing exactly this in a .ashx can be found at:
[How to post data from a webform page to an HTTPHandler.ashx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296781/how-to-post-data-from-a-webform-page-to-an-httphandler-ashx-file)
This injects a file uploader that then multipart posts the "File" data into the handler. Messy.

You may be able to do this more straightforwardly, by combining the multipart `xhr.send` from 
[XMLHttpRequest POST multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155371/xmlhttprequest-post-multipart-form-data)
with a method similar to the first part of the answer possibly using `BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);`

or

```
   //read content into a buffer
   request.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync().Wait();

   request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
   {
       apiRequest.Content = t.Result;
       _repo.Add(apiRequest);
   });
```

from [Multipart form POST using ASP.Net Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384544/multipart-form-post-using-asp-net-web-api)

or even potentially the .NET 4.5 `async` from
[how to read multi part form data in .net web api controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545788/how-to-read-multi-part-form-data-in-net-web-api-controller)

Comment: Thanks, I can have a more simple workaround, and build the excel itself in the server side, same way as the client does it to display the table to the user. What I was curious about is why does Chrome has this limitation?